# Flask - Can't Read Value from URL (Querystring)

Tags: python, flask

I have a view function defined like this:

```
@app.route('/blog', defaults={'page': 1})
@app.route('/blog?page=<int:page>')
def posts(page):
...
```

I goto this link:

http://example.com/blog?page=5

But, no matter what I try, the value of `page` is always `1`.

What am I doing wrong? Using Flask 0.10.1.

Comment: what if you change the order of the decorators?

Comment: @UkuLoskit I tried that, no difference.

Comment: I think you needn't specify the parameter in the url at all, why not use just request.args.get('page') and specify the default value as the optional argument to get.

Comment: Yes, that works (`page = request.args.get('page', default=1, type=int)`). Does Flask no longer support multiple routes for a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes don't work like that: they never match against querystring arguments. Just match on the path and get `page` from `request.args`.